# Wrapping text overwrites TextArea formatting in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jtextarea

I am currently using Java's GridBagLayout to create a GUI with TextAreas. To ensure that the GUI looks consistent from screen to screen, I decided to format the TextAreas with a specific row and column height, and use TextWrap to wrap the strings within said areas so it looks nice. Here is a sample of the code below:

```
 JFrame appFrame = new JFrame();
 appFrame.setTitle("My App");

 JTextArea nameArea;
 nameArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);
 nameArea.setText("Name: Orca" + "\n" + 
    "Other Names: Killer Whale" + "\n" +
    "Scientific Name: Orcinus orca " +
    "(Greek for kingdom of the dead " + "\n" + 
    "and/or belonging to the kingdom of Orcus)");
nameArea.setEditable(false);
nameArea.setLineWrap(true);
nameArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
appFrame.add(nameArea);

appFrame.setVisible(true);
appFrame.pack();
appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Right now I am purposely making the TextArea larger than it needs to be for testing purposes - in the finished GUI this TextArea is most likely going to be sized at 5, 15. This is one TextArea of three that I have in this project right now, but the coding for each is identical save for changes to the strings each one displays.

The problem arises when I have any text wrapping attributes set to true. It ignores the set row and column height and squishes the TextAreas into what I believe is a maximum of 6 columns wide. The number of rows seems to vary based on how large the strings contained are. I have tried using different wrap methods, such as setLineWrap and setWrapStyleWord both separately and in tandem. [Link to an image showing the squished textareas using the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk1s3.png)

I am unsure exactly what the problem in my code is. I have checked to make sure that both Eclipse and Java are fully updated, and they are. I also have checked to make sure I didn't accidentally delete a jar file somewhere along the way, and I seem to have all of them. Neither my professor nor I understand why the program is behaving this way, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1**

The one TextArea that displays the string "IMAGE HERE" will eventually be replaced with an image. I am just using the TextArea as a placeholder right now

**Edit 2**

This is the code that I use to constrain the textareas to the frame

```
GridbagConstraints layout = new GridBagConstraints();
appFrame.layout = JFrame(new GridBagLayout());

layout.gridx = 0;
layout.gridy = 0;
layout.weightx = .5;
layout.weighty = .5
layout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
layout.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
appFrame.add(nameArea, layout);
```

Comment: How do you place the `nameArea` in the layout?

Comment: I used gridbag constraints. NameArea is constrained at 0,0 with a default gridwidth and gridheight. It also has insets of 10 pixels on all sides and is anchored to the northwest portion of the grid. I'm sorry I forgot to put that in the original question.

Comment: That would be helpful if you edited your post as adding those as well.

Comment: JTextArea is designed to be placed in a JScrollPane.  The behavior probably will be closer to you want if you do that.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll add them when my next class finishes. And I'll try to see if using the scrollpane helps things. Thank you!